# Broadcom BCM43142 not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

I have a Lenovo e10 30, the WiFi is not working. 
When I go to **Software and Updates** under the **Additional Drivers** tab;
this device is using an alternative driver, and the driver that it is using is the Broadcom propriety driver.

Ubuntu 18.04 does not show the wireless card, only the ethernet network is working.

Can this problem be fixed?
I have included the output for  `sudo lshw -c network`

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 08
       serial: 50:af:73:6a:fb:e8
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:90604000-90604fff memory:90600000-90603fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:90500000-90507fff
```

---

```
sudo modprobe wl
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available
```

---

```
fatima@fatima:~$ rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Welcome to [AU](https://askubuntu.com)! what the output of `sudo lshw -C network`? please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1106615/edit) your question including that output.

Comment: We'd also like to see the result of two more commands: `sudo modprobe wl` and also: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available

Comment: fatima@fatima:~$ rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
fatima@fatima:~$

Comment: seems not to be a dupe of that... driver cannot be loaded.